# ggplot (in R)/matplotlib (in Python) with linear model?

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, ggplot2

How can I plot the histogram below, using `ggplot` (`R`) and/or `matplotlib` (`Python`)?

In base plot I use:

```
histogram(~ Wrkday | Year+Avg, data=Data, layout=c(3,2))
```

[image: graph by base plot]

The data I work on:

[image]

Code in R:

```
Input <- ("
Year       Student  Wrkday
      '1st year'  a        1200
      '1st year'  b        1400
      '1st year'  c        1350
      '1st year'  d         950
      '1st year'  e        1400
      '1st year'  f        1150
      '1st year'  g        1300
      '1st year'  h        1325
      '1st year'  i        1425
      '1st year'  j        1500
      '1st year'  k        1250
      '1st year'  l        1150
      '1st year'  m         950
      '1st year'  n        1150
      '1st year'  o        1600
      '1st year'  p        1300
      '1st year'  q        1050
      '1st year'  r        1300
      '1st year'  s        1700
      '1st year'  t        1300
      '2nd year'  u        1100
      '2nd year'  v        1200
      '2nd year'  w        1250
      '2nd year'  x        1050
      '2nd year'  y        1200
      '2nd year'  z        1250
      '2nd year'  aa       1350
      '2nd year'  ab       1350
      '2nd year'  ac       1325
      '2nd year'  ad       1525
      '2nd year'  ae       1225
      '2nd year'  af       1125
      '2nd year'  ag       1000
      '2nd year'  ah       1125
      '2nd year'  ai       1400
      '2nd year'  aj       1200
      '2nd year'  ak       1150
      '2nd year'  al       1400
      '2nd year'  am       1500
      '2nd year'  an       1200
      '3rd year'  u        1600
      '3rd year'  v        1700
      '3rd year'  w        1450
      '3rd year'  x        1650
      '3rd year'  y        1800
      '3rd year'  z        1550
      '3rd year'  aa       1950
      '3rd year'  ab       1750
      '3rd year'  ac       1925
      '3rd year'  ad       1825
      '3rd year'  ae       1625
      '3rd year'  af       1525
      '3rd year'  ag       1800
      '3rd year'  ah       1725
      '3rd year'  ai       1200
      '3rd year'  aj       1600
      '3rd year'  ak       1950
      '3rd year'  al       1100
      '3rd year'  am       1400
      '3rd year'  an       1600
      ")


Data <- read.table(textConnection(Input),header=TRUE)
los<-rbinom(nrow(Data), size = 1, prob=0.7)
Data$Avg<-ifelse(los==1,"Above 4.0","Below 4.0")
```

I would like to plot linear model in each box instead of histogram.

Comment: Do you want to create a linear model? What are you trying to do? Some example data would be good.

Comment: @wl1234, I have included a fraction of the dataset

Comment: @Learner132 I updated my answer given your comment.

Comment: Thanks, but please post data and not images of data. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @wl1234: updated

Comment: I got this, but the data in the image and your data looks different. `library(ggplot2)
ggplot(Data, aes(Wrkday, group = Year)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 100) + facet_wrap(~Avg + Year)`

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what you mean by "with linear model" in the title, but here's code that generates a toy dataset and replicates your plot.

```
library(tidyverse)
x<-crossing(year=paste("Year", 1:3), avg=c("Above 4.0", "Below 4.0"))
x$dat<-replicate(6, tibble(wrkday=runif(100, 1000, 2000)))
x %>% 
  unnest(dat) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(dat)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..ncount..), bins=20) + 
  facet_grid(avg~year)
```

[image]

EDIT:

Given your comment I think I understand what you mean by "with linear model."  You want to see how wrkday varies as a function of year, faceted by avg.  Here's some code:

```
library(tidyverse)

x<-tibble(year=sample(factor(paste("Year", 1:3)), 600, replace=T), 
          avg=sample(c("Above 4.0", "Below 4.0"), 600, replace=T)) %>%
  mutate(wrkday=rnorm(600, mean=1000*(as.integer(year)-1)/2, sd=300))

ggplot(x, aes(x=as.integer(year), y=wrkday)) + 
  geom_jitter(width=0.2) + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm") + 
  facet_wrap(~avg)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, you are really helpful, I have learned new things

Comment: Actually, the goal is to create and plot a series of linear model with wrkday as function of year/avg then both of them as well as their interaction for each year and avg. Still your code kind of giving me some new perspective.

Comment: Well, maybe you can figure it out from here.  If not, perhaps you can sketch what the chart should look like and post of photo of that.  Then I'm pretty sure I can tell you how to produce it.

Comment: Using geom_smooth(method ='lm', formula = y~x) get me there. Thank you